# Why is Leacock distance measure normalized with total taxonomy depth

Tags: python, nlp, semantics, wordnet

I am implementing an application which uses Leacock Chodorrow similarity to measure the similarity between two types.

[The similarity is defined by:](http://www.gabormelli.com/RKB/Leacock_Chodorow_Similarity_Measure)

```
-log (shortestPath(type1, type2) / (2 * taxonomyDepth))
```

My question is why the measure is normalized by the total taxonomy depth instead of the depth of the more specific type or the average of both types. My rationale behind this would be that types which have the same parent on a higher level are less similar than types which have the same parent on a lower hierarchy level. E.g. In the DBpedia ontology Activity and Agent are both children of Owl:Thing. Boxing League and Cycling League are also children of the same parent SportsLeague and would have the same Leacock chodorow similarity.

Comment: Normalizing against taxonomy depth is so that the Leacock-Chodorrow (lch) similarity is comparable against any sysnet regardless of "types". Also, the notion of sense/concept type is rather subjective depending on the task or your definition of "types".

Comment: When trying to get "local normalization", you might end up with something close to Wu-Palmer similarity. Possibly, the absolute value of your approach to local normalization but the relative similarity between pairs of synset might be the same.

Comment: In that Leacock-Chodorrow case the normalization effect would be global. But when it comes to the local differences, the relative shortest path (going through a dummy ROOT if unconnected) between pairs of synsets would achieve the same effect as normalizing against shared parent/ancestor between 2 synsets.

Comment: But the state-of-popular approach dictates that you do something like word embeddings to check similarity between words. And when it comes to sense vs word, pop-publications shrugs shoulders =)